# store Django models in a dataframe and get column names from it even though dataframe is empty

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-models

I have Django models, which is based on SQL tables, which I need to read and store in a dataframe and later retrieve just one column to work on. For first run, table would be blank because of which dataframe is coming out blank `[]`

I would need models to return blank dataframe with column names, even though data is not there. Current line of code that I've been using to retrieve model into dataframe is as follows:-

```
dt = pd.DataFrame.from_records(my_table.objects.all().values())
my_val = dt.col1.iat[-1]
```

currently, code is failing with following error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col1'
```

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Comment: I am stuck in the same situation as well. As far as I get it - you want(ed) to get an **empty** dataframe from the **empty** model before importing data from an external source. I also need some way to create dataframe only containing the model fields. **Have you been able to get an solution to your query?**

Answer (score 0):

Pass `columns` parameter with the names of your columns, matching the order of the actual columns of the data.

For example, like this:

```
dt = pd.DataFrame.from_records(my_table.objects.all().values(), columns['col1','col2','col3'])
```

Quoting the documentation of the parameter:

> ```
> columns : sequence, default None
>     Column names to use. If the passed data do not have names
>     associated with them, this argument provides names for the
>     columns. Otherwise this argument indicates the order of the columns
>     in the result (any names not found in the data will become all-NA
>     columns)
> ```